# SequelizeJS: Recursive include same model

Tags: postgresql, recursion, sequelize.js

I want to fetch data from a Postgres database recursively including all associated models using [SequelizeJS](http://sequelizejs.com).

**GeoLocations table**

```
id | isoCode | name | parentId | type | updatedAt | deletedAt
```

`parentId` holds the id of the parent GeoLocation.

**Model Associations**

```
GeoLocation.belongsTo(GeoLocation, {
    foreignKey: 'parentId',
    as: 'GeoLocation'
});
```

**Data explanation and example**

GeoLocation types and their relations:
`city -> subdivision -> country -> continent`

```
id: 552, name: Brooklyn, type: city, parentId: 551
id: 551, name: New York, type: subdivision, parentId: 28
id: 28, name: United States, type: country, parentId: 27
id: 27, name: North America, type: continent, parentId: NULL
```

Now, when querying a city, I want all relations to be included as long as `parentId` is set.

```
GeoLocation.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 552
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: GeoLocation,
            as: 'GeoLocation',
            include: [
                {
                    model: GeoLocation,
                    as: 'GeoLocation',
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: GeoLocation,
                            as: 'GeoLocation',
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
});
```

**Response in JSON**

```
{  
   "GeoLocation":{  
      "id":552,
      "type":"city",
      "name":"Brooklyn",
      "GeoLocation":{  
         "id":551,
         "type":"subdivision",
         "name":"New York",
         "GeoLocation":{  
            "id":28,
            "type":"country",
            "name":"United States",
            "GeoLocation":{  
               "id":27,
               "type":"continent",
               "name":"North America"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The solution above works, but I have the strong feeling, that there are better ways to do this, without having to include the model multiple times. I can't find anything related in the docs. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am looking for same thiing, and for MariaDB :) If you happened to overcome this, share your solution ^^

Comment: @Deunz Nah, I stuck with this until the end of the project. But I would still love to see a better solution than this :)

Answer (score 0):

I already moved on a different solution. I am not using sequelize native pseudo language to achieve this. Because **apparently**, recursive includes feature is not possible with sequelize.

Here is the recursive model I use :
[image: Recursive model]

I want this recursive info, which organisation is related to which, no matter how I get this info, I'll process it later to get the info into shape (tree, flat list, ... whatever)

I use a sequelize RAW query involving recursive SQL:

```
exports.getArborescenceByLienId = function (relationType, id) {
    const query = 'With cte as (\n' +
        '    select  id_organisationSource, \n' +
        '            relationType,\n' +
        '            id_organisationTarget\n' +
        '    from    (\n' +
        '                    select * from relation where relationType= :relationType\n'     +
        '                ) relations_sorted,\n' +
        '            (\n' +
        '                  select @pv := :orgId\n' +
        '                ) initialisation\n' +
        '    where   find_in_set(id_organisationSource, @pv)\n' +
        '    and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, \',\', id_organisationTarget))\n' +
        ')\n' +
        'select source.id as `idSource`, cte.relationType, target.id as `idTarget`\n' +
        'from cte \n' +
        'left outer join organisation source on cte.id_organisationSource = source.id\n' +
        'left outer join organisation target on cte.id_organisationTarget = target.id;';
    return models.sequelize.query(
        query,
        {
            type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
            replacements: { orgId: id, relationType: relationType}
        }
    );
};
```

Imagine I have an object model like this:

[image: Recursive object model]
(Assuming each relation here have same type : say isManaging)
Result of query with ID = 1 would be :
[image: Query result ID1]

Result of query with ID = 2 would be : 
[image: Query result ID2]

I then transform this flat list to a Tree, and VOILA :)

Let me know if your interested in this Flat list to tree transforming algorithm.

Hope this help. Cheers !